# How to find out module path in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have such code:

A.js

```
module.exports = function() {
/*
    Here I need to find out the path of module in which this function was called.
*/
};
```

B.js

```
var A = require('./A.js');

A();
```

C.js

```
var A = require('./A.js');

A();
```

Is it possible to find out from which file function of module A is called? I know that I can pass __filename param:

```
var A = require('./A.js');

A(__filename);
```

but maybe there is another way without passing any params to A()?

Comment: `module.parent.filename`

Comment: You can also look into using `require.resolve(<module-name>);`

Comment: I updated my post, added comment inside module A.js.

module.parent.filename - it is not what I need because module.parent is always the first module who called another module.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, then the answer is No.  A function in Javascript does not know the filename of its caller in any standard way that is documented in a specification.  There are some hacks using the exception stack trace, but it is not recommended to use that for a variety of reasons.

You don't explain why you're trying to do this, but in general a function should not change its behavior based on who the caller is.  Rather a function should have a defined behavior based on the arguments passed to it.  If you want a different behavior when called from B.js and from C.js, then you should specify some argument when calling it in each circumstance that indicates what the behavior should be or create different functions that can be called to generate the different behaviors.

Comment: The behavior must be the same, but it is necessary to know filename from which this function is called. I just wanted to pass less params to my function. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @pavel06081991 - if you're doing something based on the filename, then the behavior is not the same.  As always, we can help so much better if you don't keep the actual problem to be solved a mystery.

Comment: You are wrong :) As I said the behavior of the function is always the same. Filename is used as a key name in an object. I found a solution of my problem. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @pavel06081991 - It should probably be an argument to the function then since that's how you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible, but you really should not do this. You can examine the error stack to get the calling file path like this:

```
function getCallingFile(n) {
  // Regular expression used to extract the file path
  var exp = / \(([^:]+)(:[^\)]+)?\)$/;
  // Extract line from error stack
  var line = new Error().stack.split('\n')[1 + n];
  // Try to find path in that line
  var m = exp.exec(line);
  if(m) {
    return m[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The parameter `n` means how many levels of the stack should be skipped, in your example it should be 1.

Why shouldn't you do this? Because

1. the exact format of `err.stack` has not been specified formally,
2. this function will fail if you call it from native code,
3. it is not what error stacks have been designed for and
4. it enforces a specific directory which might cause problems if you ever refactor your code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. But why should I not do this if it works? :)

Comment: @pavel06081991 I added an explanation, hope that helps.

Comment: It is the only way, there are no other ways, am I right?

Comment: @pavel06081991 There are other approaches, e.g. [this project](https://github.com/iriscouch/traceback) uses `Error.prepareStackTrace` to access raw stack frames which are less error-prone than my suggestion, but require a difficult setup and can cause performance loss. The most reliable solution might be a native binding, but I never tried that.